# SQLite3 IF statement, condition based on other columns

Tags: sqlite, case, conditional-statements

Here's my table:

```
sqlite> SELECT * from portafolio WHERE my_id=1;
id          my_id       stock       name           shares      price       date               
----------  ----------  ----------  -------------  ----------  ----------  -------------------
1           1           NFLX        Netflix, Inc.  2           133.26      2017/01/19  06:40AM
2           1           GM          General Motor  1           37.47       2017/01/19  06:40AM
3           1           NFLX        Netflix, Inc.  -2          133.26      2017/01/19  06:41AM
4           1           NFLX        Netflix, Inc.  4           133.26      2017/01/19  06:41AM
```

I'd like to make the `price` negative if `shares` is negative.

I know that I have to use `CASE` but don't know how to properly implement it, here's my attempt:

```
sqlite> SELECT CASE 
   ...> WHEN shares<0
   ...> THEN price=price*-1
   ...> END, stock,shares,price FROM portafolio;
```

Output:

```
CASE
WHEN shares<0
THEN price=price*-1
END  stock       shares      price     
------------------------------------------  ----------  ----------  ----------
                                            NFLX        2           133.26    
                                            GM          1           37.47     
0                                           NFLX        -2          133.26    
                                            NFLX        4           133.26    
                                            ST          1           41.2      
                                            HA          5           56.65     
0                                           ST          -1          41.2      
0                                           HA          -3          56.65     
0                                           HA          -2          56.65     
                                            GM          1           37.47     
0                                           GM          -1          37.47
```

Any help would be appreciated guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any `ELSE` case in your query. Without `ELSE` there will be no results if `shares` is less than zero. Also, you don't need to assign `price * -1` to `price`. Just use it like this:

```
CASE WHEN shares < 0
     THEN price * -1
     ELSE price
END
```